# specifying the color of a string

Tags: python, fwrite

I want write some data to a python file using file.write(). is there a way I can specify the color of strings when writing it?
eg:

```
file = open("myFile.py", "w")
file.write("I like apple")
file.close()
```

is there a way where I can specify the color of "I like apple"?

Comment: A string is just a sequence of characters. It doesn't have a colour, any more than a number has a colour.

Comment: No, this is not possible, if you write plain text to a text file.

Comment: You need to add precisions to your question: do you want the color to appear in a linux terminal when you `cat` the file? In a browser (if the file is .html)? In Word (if the file is .doc)?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the color of text using a plain text file, since no format information is carried with it.

You can use a rich text format, for example ODF (https://pypi.org/project/odfpy/) or RTF (https://pypi.org/project/PyRTF/) and give it color.

If the text file is to be displayed **only in a text terminal** (i.e. using `cat` or similars) and it should be displayed only in Linux/Mac systems, you can use terminal escape sequences to create the color, and that will indeed work. To do so:

```py
color = 1 # red
file.write("\033[3" + color + "mTest\033[0m")
```

The color palette is:

```
0 black
1 red
2 green
3 yellow
4 blue
5 magenta
6 cyan
7 white
```

You can also change the `"\033[3"` with `"\033[9"` for a brighter color palette.

When displaying the text file with a terminal, the colors will be displayed, but in most visual text editors colors will not be visible and the content will mostly be garbled.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need are simple colors, and maybe a font or two, you can write out the RTF file with Python. I have a program that outputs an RTF file with colored words.
I define an almost RTF template (just missing a final `}`) like this (all on one line):

```
template = '{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\nouicompat\\deflang1033{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}}\n{\\colortbl;\\red255\\green0\\blue0;\\red0\\green0\\blue255;\\red0\\green255\\blue0;\\red255\\green0\\blue255;}'
```

After marking up a text file with the colors defined above (`\cf1\b day\cf0\b0` marks up "day" as bold red),
I write the template + the text file + `}` to an RTF file.
When opened in Word or Wordpad or WordPerfect, presto: colored words.